# Posting a message to a Modal dialog box in another thread

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-studio, atl

I am trying to build a logging window for an ATL COM object. My aim is to kick off an ATL CWorkerThread which opens a modal dialog box (compiled from a VS resource) which contains one child multi-line edit box:

CLogProcessor implements the IWorkerThreadClient interface:

```
class CLogProcessor : public IWorkerThreadClient
{
    HANDLE m_hEvent;
    HANDLE m_hLogReady;
    CWorkerThread<Win32ThreadTraits> m_wtThread;
    CMyDialog* m_pDlg;
public:
    CLogProcessor();
    ~CLogProcessor();

    HRESULT Execute(DWORD_PTR dwParam, HANDLE hObject);
    HRESULT CloseHandle(HANDLE hHandle);
};
```

And this is the Execute function to kick off the worker thread:

```
HRESULT CLogProcessor::Execute(DWORD_PTR dwParam, HANDLE hObject)
{
    if (m_pDlg == 0)
    {
        m_pDlg = new CMyDialog();
        m_pDlg->SetReadyHandle(m_hLogReady); //m_hLogReady is an event set at the end of InitDialog
        m_pDlg->DoModal();
    }

    if (m_pDlg)
    {
        ::ResetEvent(m_hLogReady);
        delete m_pDlg;
        m_pDlg = 0;
    }

    ::ResetEvent(m_hEvent); //m_hEvent is the event which kicks off the thread
    return S_OK;
}
```

This works in that when the COM object starts the logging, the worker thread is created and the modal dialog box pops up, and stays there until other code closes it. I want to post messages to the EditBox with logging information strings from the main client thread.

```
bool CLogProcessor::AddString(const string& strText, bool bCR)
{
    if (m_pDlg)
    {
        string str = strText + (bCR ? "\r\n" : "");
        std::wstring ws = std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
        CWindow eb(m_pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)); //This is the EditBox

        if (!eb.PostMessage(EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)ws.c_str())) 
        {
            DWORD dwErr = 0;
            const DWORD dwSize = 100 + 1;
            WCHAR buffer[dwSize];           
            dwErr = GetLastError();
            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,0,dwErr,0,buffer,dwSize,NULL);
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      return false;
 }
```

If I replace PostMessage() with SendMessage(), the thing works and the logging string is displayed in the EditBox ... but it is synchronous, which kind of defeats the point of having a worker thread.

But PostMessage() fails with "The message can be used only with synchronous operations."

Perhaps the EM_REPLACESEL message for the EditBox is not the right message to add a new line to my EditBox? I suppose I could keep an internal buffer of strings in the modal dialog and poll this for new strings to add, rather than use windows messages.

I am open to suggestions!

Comment: The parameters to `EM_REPLACESEL` need to remain valid until the message has been processed. Specifically, `lParam` points to a character array. You're going to have to learn about object lifetimes if you want to succeed in writing multi-threaded code. There aren't any alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable! For some reason I assumed that windows messages were copied to some system memory somewhere. Looks like I'd be better off keeping a stack of strings shared between the threads, with thread-safe access to push and pop. Then a worker thread that creates a modeless Dialog box, with a loop that checks the stack until told to stop, and uses synchronous SendMessages to populate the EditBox.